# OpenXML table gridSpan property

Tags: openxml, libreoffice, openxml-table

I have created a DOCX document in *LibreOffice 5.3.7.2.0+* with a table like the following:

```
+-------+---+---+---+
|   A   | B | C | D |
+---+---+---+---+---+
| E | F | G | H | I |
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

You can see that cell `A` is two cells in width, all other cells have an equal size.

I read that the `gridSpan` property defines the cell's logical width [in the documentation](http://officeopenxml.com/WPtableGrid.php).

I unzipped the created `docx` file and took a look inside the `document.xml` file: https://gist.github.com/erdos/3a69e5c5a9eb8ea26c4f8fc5951bc127

Strangely, it seems that the `gridSpan` values in the xml file just do not match with what I see in the editor.

- The xml file contains the following `gridSpan` values: `2,2,2,1  1,1,1,2,2`
- However from what i see on the screen I would expect something like: `2,1,1,1   1,1,1,1,1`

Why is the difference? To I misunderstand the purpose and use of `gridSpan`? Thank you very much!

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  I tried this with LO 5.4.3.2 and it produced only one line with `<w:gridSpan w:val="2"/>`.  Did you create the table starting from a blank document?  Perhaps it would help to give the exact steps to create the table.  For example, maybe "G" and "H" were originally created as two columns each and then you merged them.  However I tried that and it did not produce your results either.